# Solving $\int_0^1 \sqrt{x^2+1}$ with Euler substitution

Tags: analysis, definite-integrals

So I was trying to solve this integral

$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{x^2+1} \, dx$$

in two different ways with Euler substitution. So:

1. $(x^2+1)=x+t$, so that $x=(1-t^2)/(2t)$,
2. $(x^2+1)=x*t+1$, $x=2t/(1-t^2)$.

But I am not sure how to proceed, and how do the integral and the limits change... Any tips? Thanks :)

Comment: is it $x^2-1$ or $1-x^2$

Comment: it's + , sorry for the mistake

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: It does not look like those changes are going to work. You could try $x=\tan t$ but there is still some work ahead.

Comment: @MiguelAtencia Why wouldn't it work? It is much more work than the conventional $x=tant$ sub, but Euler sub can work:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution

Answer (score 2):

Put $x=\sinh (t)=\frac {e^t-e^{-t}}{2} $

then

$x=0$ gives $t=0$

$x=1$ gives $t $ such that

$$e^t-e^{-t}=2$$
that is
$$(e^t)^2-2e^t-1=0$$
$$t=\ln (1+\sqrt {2})$$

thus the integral becomes

$$\int_0^{\ln (1+\sqrt {2})}\cosh^2 (t)dt $$

$$=\int_0^{\ln (1+\sqrt {2})}\frac {1+\cosh (2t)}{2}dt $$

$$=\frac {1}{2}\ln (1+\sqrt {2})+\frac {1}{8}((1+\sqrt {2})^2-(1-\sqrt {2})^2) $$

i am sure you can finish.

Comment: i already did this. My task is to do it with  Euler substitution...

Comment: @SimonJachson What do you mean by Euler substitution. $e^{it}... $

Answer (score 0):

@Salahamam With Euler substitution it is meant a particular kind of substitution  discovered by Euler for integrals containing a squareroot and a quadratic polynomial inside. See my link in a comment. It is not about $e^{it}$ here. The substitution in question is $\sqrt{x^2+1}=x+t$. Now solving this for $x$ to get: $x=\frac{1-t^2}{2t}$ and so $dx=\frac{-2t^2-2}{4t^2}dt$. The given integral is of the form $\int\frac{1-t^2+2t^2}{2t}*\frac{-2t^2-2}{4t^2}dt$. Enfin, this is now all polynomial work where the denominator is a monomial and so after the numerator is worked out, one can split fractions and integrate. Please give it a try from here. This is just (annoying) algebra...

Comment: Thanks but it is much easier with hyperbolic sinus.

Comment: Thanks!! and how does the limits changes here , 1/4 lower and 1 upper ?

Comment: @SimonJachson i think the lower is $\sqrt {2}-1$

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima I agree that the Euler substitution is a bit cumbersome and that other methods like the hyperbolic sine or tangent substitutions are easier. I wouldn't choose the Euler sub either for this case, but that is what the OP wanted. And limit changes, that shouldn't be to difficult.You can find that from the given sub